# Double Check of entered PIN for equality

Tags: python

I need to write a python code which checks for equality for the entered pin second time and then proceeds further. Here is how my code goes:

```
id1 = int(input("Enter 4-digit account pin: "))
id2 = int(input("Re-Enter 4-digit account pin for confirmation: "))
if id1 == id2:
    id = id1
else:
    id2 = int(input("Incorrect pin.. Please Re-enter: "))
```

Here after my pin gets verified it needs to get assigned to a variable named `id`. But the above code works only when I enter the incorrect pin once. If I enter again, the code continues to the next step. I want the code to repeat the equality check until both the entered pins are equal and after confirmed as equal, needed to get assigned to the variable `id`. Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "repeat the equality check"?

Comment: use while loop, while id1!=id2:
                            id2 = (take input)
                            id = id1            Further downvoting this question.

Comment: I meant by the if condition, the line which says ```if id1 == id2```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
id1 = int(input("Enter 4-digit account pin: "))
id2 = int(input("Re-Enter 4-digit account pin for confirmation: "))
while id1 != id2:
    id2 = int(input("Incorrect pin.. Please Re-enter: "))
id = id1
```

This repeatedly asks for PIN confirmation until the two values are equal.

Comment: What if the mistake was actually on `id1`?  You never ask for that input again.

Comment: It doesn't matter whatever was entered in id1. At the end I need id1 to be equal to id2

Comment: The OP didn't mention that, so I assumed it would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole thing in a `while id1 != id2` loop.

```
# initialize to different values so the input loop will run at least once
id1 = 1
id2 = 2

# keep asking for both inputs until they are equal
while id1 != id2:
    id1 = int(input(...))
    id2 = int(input(...))

    if id1 != id2:
        print("Incorrect.  Please re-enter")

# loop is done, so id1 is the same as id2
id = id1
```

Comment: Also a valid answer, but I think the OP was looking for something more like mine. +1